# Where to add application.properties file in ecclipse when using spring boot

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am very new to spring. Just trying to figure out how to run a simple application. I am using Kepler eclipse. I have created a simple Java project and converted it maven. Now i am wondering where is the application.properties file or where to add it so that spring boot identifies itautomatically when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. If i create a spring starter project then application.properties is generated automatically.